# How to group users roles in Meteor Js

Tags: meteor

Can someone help me to solve this problem? I want to assign multiple users to become admin for each category.

For example I have collections:

```
User:{emily, bob, roberts, alex}

Category:{Laptop, Computer, Tablet, Network}
```

How can I assigned roles for emily to become admin for Laptop and Computer? Besides, Bob and Alex are admin for Network?

Your kindness and help really appreciated. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Are you using the [roles package](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) or writing your own implementation?

Comment: I'm using alanning roles. Is it possible to assign user for each category. Hope you can help..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old. But if someone is searching similar.

Lets assume you have your users in users-collection like this.

```
var emily = Meteor.users.findOne({name: "Emily"});
var bob = Meteor.users.findOne({name: "Bob"});
var roberts = Meteor.users.findOne({name: "Roberts"});
var alex = Meteor.users.findOne({name: "Alex"});
```

Then you can put users to roles like this:

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles(emily._id, ['Laptop', 'Computer'], 'admin');
Roles.addUsersToRoles(bob._id, ['Network'], 'admin');
Roles.addUsersToRoles(alex._id, ['Network'], 'admin');
```

In if you look at users-collection's Emily-record you see Emily's roles:

```
"roles" : {
        "admin" : [
                "Laptop",
                "Computer"

        ]
}
```

Then, if you want to check if user is admin for some group you can try it:

If 
Roles.userIsInRole(emily._id, 'Laptop', 'admin') // == true
Roles.userIsInRole(emily._id, 'Network', 'admin') // == false
Roles.userIsInRole(bob._id, 'Laptop', 'admin') // == false
Roles.userIsInRole(bob._id, 'Network', 'admin') // == true

or from templates

```
{{#if isInRole 'Computers' 'admin'}}
{{/if}}
```

If you have categories in db

```
var network_category = Categories.findOne({..})

Roles.userIsInRole(bob._id, network_category.name, 'admin') // == true
```